# Get FaultInfo WSDL

Tags: java, c#, wsdl

Im consuming an API(written in Java) , i generated an Proxy from the WSDL.

and trying to get the FaultInfo(SaveContactToListFaultInfo) to get the error details,  my client is in C#. below is the part of WSDL

WSDL

```
<xsd:element name="SaveContactToList">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="ContactToBeSaved" type="tns:ContactDataType"/>
            <xsd:element default="false" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="AutomaticUpdateForTimeZone" type="xsd:boolean"/>
            <xsd:element default="false" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="CheckForRejectPattern" type="xsd:boolean"/>
            <xsd:element default="false" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="CheckForPhoneFormatsRule" type="xsd:boolean"/>
            <xsd:element default="false" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="UpdateExisting" type="xsd:boolean"/>
            <xsd:element default="false" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="CheckDNC" type="xsd:boolean"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="SaveContactToListResponse">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Result" type="xsd:int"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="SaveContactToListFaultInfo">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="RetCode" type="xsd:int"/>
            <xsd:element name="FaultMsg" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Any help ? how to get the **RetCode** and **FaultMsg** ?

Answer (score 0):

At last i  end up writing an Soap extension and manage the response code.

[SOAP Extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7w06t139(v=vs.100).aspx)